# Find the position vectors of points B and C, both lying on a line, such that the length AB = AC = 10

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

> The position vector of the point $A$ is $2\vec{i} - \vec{k}$ and the equation of the the line is:
>
> $$\vec{r} = (-7, 15, -5) + \lambda (3, -7, 4) \ . $$
>
> Find the position vectors of points $B$ and $C$, both lying on the line, such that the length $\overline{AB} = \overline{AC} = 10$.

So this is what I've done so far:

I found the foot of the perpendicular from point $A$ to the line and labeled that $M$. Using the fact that point $M$ lies on the line and that it is perpendicular to the director vector of the line, I found the coordinate of point $M$ (-1, 1, 3). Now that I have the position vector of point $M$ and the magnitude of $\overline{AC}$, I can find the magnitude of $\overline{MC}$ using the Pythagoras Theorem but I don't know how to continue from there and or if I am at all on the right path.

Comment: Sorry about that but I don't know how to edit the question so that matches the quality standards. I was simply having some trouble with some homework and I thought I would try posting here as I couldn't find a similar question being answered anywhere else

Comment: Please say what have you tried. For instance, can you write the formula for the distance between $A$ and a point on the line for $\lambda$ unknown?

Comment: Did you look at the link in the first comment that said it would "help you recognize and resolve the issues"? It leads to more links; did you look at [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933)? By showing some effort, even if it goes nowhere or leads you in a circle back to where you started, you give us clues about what kind of help to give.

Comment: Hopefully it is better now. Sorry about messing up this is my first time. And thank you @Ertxiem for suggesting the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it the way you are working, but it seems to me that it's going to give you a bit more work that just solving:
$$ \overline{AR}^2 = 10^2$$
with $R=( -7 + 3 \lambda, 15 -7 \lambda, -5 + 4 \lambda )$.

It will give a quadratic polynomial for $\lambda$, hence the two solutions.

Can you solve this?

---

**Edit:**

Since $A = (2, 0, -1)$, then the square of the distance between $A$ and the generic point of the straight line $r$ is:

$$
\overline{AR}^2 =  (-7 + 3 \lambda - 2)^2 + (15 -7 \lambda - 0)^2 + (-5 + 4 \lambda - 1)^2 
$$

Since we want $\overline{AR}^2 = 10^2$, we get
$$
(-7 + 3 \lambda - 2)^2 + (15 -7 \lambda - 0)^2 + (-5 + 4 \lambda - 1)^2 = 100
$$

Which gives:
$$
(3 \lambda - 9)^2 + (15 -7 \lambda)^2 + (4 \lambda - 6)^2 = 100
$$
$$
9 \lambda^2 - 54 \lambda + 81 + 225 -210 \lambda + 49 \lambda^2 + 16 \lambda^2 -24 \lambda + 36 = 100
$$

Now, you just need to solve the quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$.

Comment: Nope not really. I don't understand what $R$ represents, why you squared the expression and how you would get a quadratic polynomial from that. I should be able to solve for $\lambda$ and find the position vectors of $B$ and $C$ from there though

Comment: So by subbing $R$ into $\overline{AR}$ i got $( 81 - 54 \lambda +9 \lambda^2, 225 - 210 \lambda +49 \lambda^2, 36 - 48 \lambda +16 \lambda^2 ) $ = 100. How do I continue? Do i just add all of them up and set them equal to 100 and solve for $\lambda$?

Comment: The distance is the sum of the square of difference for each coordinate. I added those steps in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You’re most of the way there. Once you’ve used the Pythagorean theorem to determine the distance of the two points from $M$, you just need to move that far along the line in both directions. The direction vector given in the parametric equation of the line is $(3,-7,4)$, so you just have to find a suitable multiple of this that has the required length.